PHP shell_exec fails, terminal/CLI works
I have to get basic information about the operating system in PHP:
$p = shell_exec('cat /etc/*-release 2>&1');
This returns:
cat: '/etc/*-release': No such file or directory
The command runs fine in the terminal/CLI via PuTTY.
My current best interpretation is that PHP requires a path to be set. So I tried this:
$p = shell_exec('echo $PATH');
Which returns:
/bin:/usr/bin
When I run echo $PATH in the terminal directly I get a : delimited list. So I took all of those and put them in the PHP file directly as so:
putenv('/etc');
//plus others
Still no result. I know shell_exec() works fine with other commands shell_exec('whoami');. In the terminal/CLI I am logged in as the exact same user as PHP 8.3.
What else am I missing?

The problem was that PHP was setup to run in chroot jail. I had exhausted all other possibilities. I only even discovered it thanks to @vidarlo's comment.
I was able to resolve the issue in WHM via the CageFS plugin. The Linux user that PHP uses was set to execute and I removed it from the association.

There's multiple problems here.

Do people even read the error messages they get?
Don't use shell commands to read a file to a variable! Use fopen.
Don't do globbing. Globs are expanded by the shell, but PHP is not a shell, so it doesn't do globbing. It hands your exact command off to the shell, and asks the shell to execute it. And yes, *-release is a valid filename.

    [~]$ ls -la /tmp/\*-releases 
    -rw-r--r-- 1 vidarlo users 0 Jun 23 10:16 /tmp/*-releases
    [~]$ 


Globbing potentially opens you to attacks. If you glob, you have no control over what files you end up reading. That's a potential security issue. Probably not in this case, as you're reading from /etc, but...
You lack a basic understanding about your environment, when you expect that modifying a path parameter will change anything - the problem is not that cat command is not found, it's that the file you give as parameter is not found... A general understanding of the platform is a good starting point for programming.
putenv('/etc'); is not how putenv works. Environment variables are generally key=value-pairs.
Don't post it on serverfault. It's not about managing IT, it's purely about programming. Additionally, you should probably spend some time to learn the platform you're working on.


I tried it with a normally named file that also contains the information and it resulted with: fopen(/etc/[file name here]): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory. That file has a 644 CHMOD and I'm only calling fopen with r for read. Not ignoring your security warnings though this stuff is only for internal purposes.

Do you run in a chroot jail?

I had no idea, looked it up, tried stat -c %i / and it returned 2 so I'm guessing yes in a grand total of ~three minutes. Suggestions please?

While not technically the answer +1 for helping me in the right direction with chroot.
